# JavaFX Changing Button Color

Tags: javafx

I have a button that I change to the color green using

```
button.setStyle();
```

Now I need to make it back to the default color. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the styles you have set with `button.setStyle("");`

Comment: Also, if I want to change the text inside of a button, can I do that with a set method?

Comment: You know there is [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/control/Button.html) that lists all the methods every class defines (and inherits), right?

Comment: You just need to use button.setText("value");